# Go lang executing javascript for retrieving text in page

Tags: javascript, html, go, html-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve text that is loaded dynamically from a web page using golang.

The text to retrieve is on this page : 
https://www.protectedtext.com/testretrieve?1234

This text is encrypted by a password and then decrypted on client side and loaded dynamically on the page.

I already tried with goquery by selecting 'textarea' object, but I can't get the text cause it's loaded dynamically.

How can I achieve this ? By executing JS in Go ? It's working in my chrome console, but no ideas on how to do that in Go.

A lightweight solution is the best for my project. Or any other website that can store and edit same text without modifying the URL ?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this (there are JS interpreters for Go, and a headless Chrome driver came out recently), but nothing built-in, so this is off-topic for SO as a request for third-party resources. Also you should know that there is no *easy* way to do this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a headless browser to load the javascript like for example [phantomgo](https://github.com/k4s/phantomgo)

However looking at the page source code we can see that they use `sha512` for the tab title and `aes` for the textarea field.

Answer (score 0):

The page which you shared contains  https://www.protectedtext.com/testretrieve?1234,  only one element of class textarea-contents
simple get class documents using goquery and get 0th part